# UISplitView popup button not showing when put in a view controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uiwindow

I took the apple standard example, MultiDetailView and just added a generic view controller in between the app delegate and the split view controller.

```
window > view controller > UISplitViewController
```

In terms of code, I just change from

```
[window addSubview:splitView.view];
```

to

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

and within the generic view controller subclass

```
[self.view addSubview:splitView.view];
```

However, the act of doing so makes the standard left popup button to disappear in portrait view.

How do I get the standard left popup button to appear again?